# error when trying to save dataframe spark to a hdfs file

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming

I'm using Ubuntu

When i try to save a dataframe to HDFS (Spark Scala):

```scala
processed.write.format("json").save("hdfs://localhost:54310/mydata/enedis/POC/processed.json")
```

I got this error

> Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(org.apache.hadoop.security.AccessControlException): Permission denied: user=root, access=WRITE, inode="/mydata/enedis/POC":hadoop_amine:supergroup:drwxr-xr-x

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to write data as `root` user but hdfs directory(/mydata/enedis/POC)  having permissions to `hadoop_amine` user to write to the directory.

Change the [permissions](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/HdfsPermissionsGuide.html) on the HDFS directory to allow `root` user to write to `/mydata/enedis/POC` directory.

```
#login as hadoop_amine user then execute below command
hdfs dfs –chmod -R 777  /mydata/enedis/POC
```

---

**`(Or)`**

Intialize the spark shell with `hadoop_amine` user then no need to change the permissions of the directory.

Comment: thank you it worked perfectly :) , can you tell me how to Intialize the spark shell with hadoop_amine , cause im using only spark dependency on intellij

Comment: i think i deleted your comment by mistake :s , i will open a new thread for  Intialize the spark shell

Comment: @aminedjeddi, Sure.. that's a good idea, so that question will get much more visibility..!

Comment: i opened the new thread  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61582859/how-to-intialize-the-spark-shell-with-a-specific-user-to-save-data-to-hdfs-by-ap