# how to Intialize the spark shell with a specific user to save data to hdfs by apache spark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming

- im using ubuntu
- im using spark dependency using intellij
- Command 'spark' not found, but can be installed with: .. (when i enter spark in shell)
- i have two user amine , and `hadoop_amine` (where hadoop hdfs is set)

when i try to save a dataframe to HDFS (spark scala):

```
procesed.write.format("json").save("hdfs://localhost:54310/mydata/enedis/POC/processed.json")
```

i got this error

```
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(org.apache.hadoop.security.AccessControlException): Permission denied: user=root, access=WRITE, inode="/mydata/enedis/POC":hadoop_amine:supergroup:drwxr-xr-x
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change the permissions of the `HDFS` directory or change your spark user simply!
For changing the directory permission you can use `hdfs` command line like this

```
hdfs dfs -chmod  ...
```

In `spark-submit` you can use the `proxy-user` option
And at last, you can run the `spark-submit` or `spark-shell` with the proper user like this command:

```
sudo -u hadoop_amine spark-submit ...
```