# Problem with HDFS permissions when running PySpark on YARN (via Zeppelin)

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, hadoop-yarn, apache-zeppelin

I am trying to run a PySpark script from Zeppelin on a YARN cluster which I have set up myself.  It is failing with this error (in Zeppelin):

```
[INFO] org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client logInfo - Preparing resources for our AM container
[ERROR] org.apache.spark.SparkContext logError - Error initializing SparkContext.
org.apache.hadoop.security.AccessControlException: Permission denied: user=myuser, access=WRITE, inode="/user/myuser/.sparkStaging/application_1587076034113_0005":root:supergroup:drwxr-
xr-x
```

Zeppelin is running as 'myuser'.  I have created a /user/myuser folder in HDFS these commands:

```
hdfs dfs -mkdir /user/myuser
hdfs dfs -chown -R myuser:mygroup /user/myuser
hdfs dfs -chmod 766 /user/myuser  

hdfs dfs -ls /user
Found 3 items
drwxrw-rw-   - myuser mygroup          0 2020-05-16 20:10 /user/myuser
```

My understanding is the Spark Driver is trying to set up its dependencies on the YARN cluster.  I don't know why, but the /user/myuser/.sparkStaging/application directory in HDFS is still owned by root, so myuser user doesn't have permission to write to it.

I don't know what I'm missing here - I was expecting the .sparkStaging directory and it's contents to be owned by myuser.

At the moment HDFS is running as root (not for long).

Thanks in advance

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to Intialize the spark shell with a specific user to save data to hdfs by apache spark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61582859/how-to-intialize-the-spark-shell-with-a-specific-user-to-save-data-to-hdfs-by-ap)

Comment: check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61582859/how-to-intialize-the-spark-shell-with-a-specific-user-to-save-data-to-hdfs-by-ap/61609619#61609619